# Is it possible to create a global attach() handler for viewmodels?

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I have a use case with Aurelia where I would like to have a handler run for every view that is attached. (It's an HTML5 polyfill for date and number inputs that would work via `querySelector`.) I realize that I could call this within every view that I create, but I'm wondering if there's a best practice to set this at a global level. (Note: This could probably be done with a router pipeline step, but all views may not be subject to that, such as views loaded via `compose`.)

I realize that this could potentially be dangerous, but is there a best practice to add global `attached()` and `detached()` handlers for views and viewmodels?

Edit: Looking here (https://github.com/aurelia/templating/blob/ee5b9d6742fddf3d163aee8face6e6a58ba1554c/src/view.js#L259) it looks as though it would be possible to add a hook for a global handler here that took a view as an argument, but I'd rather not have to change the framework code if possible.

Answer (score 1):

My idea would be to create a base viewmodel class with an `attached` logic, which would contain globally required functionality.
Extended viewmodels could call `super.attached()` to execute global logic as needed.

You can find a demo here: https://gist.run/?id=fea4069d8a4361c4802c7c5d42105145

This can work with `compose` as well. I know, it isn't a completely automated solution but an opt-in method, so it would require a bit of additional work on all viewmodels.

**Base class** - used by all viewmodels

```
import { inject } from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(Element)
export class BaseView {

  constructor(element) {
    this.element = element;
  }

  attached() {
    // global logic goes here
  }

}
```

**Example viewmodel** - actual implementation

```
import { BaseView } from './base-view';
import { inject } from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(Element)
export class ExtendedView extends BaseView {

  constructor(element) {
    super(element);
  }

  attached() {
    super.attached(); // global logic runs
  }

}
```